# Inserting a default GUID value into table columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to seed a table, and for the initial data load I would like the `CreateBy` column to have the value of the default GUID `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Is there a simple way to do this? Is there a way to get `NEWID()` to generate the default value?

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? A column named "CreateBy" implies a string datatype (like a login or user name).

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YOUR_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_UID DEFAULT CAST ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FOR COLUMN_NAME
```

Just add a default to the column

Answer (score 0):

You could just explicitly cast this string:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(createdBy)
VALUES (CAST ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach is to cast a binary zero to a guid:

```
SELECT CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

This will be casted implicitly actually. Try this:

Setting a typed GUID-variable to `0x0`

```
DECLARE @id1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @id1=0x0;
SELECT @id1;
```

Assign `0x0` directly

```
DECLARE @id2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=0x0;
SELECT @id2;
```

Or use this against a table's column:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO @tbl(id) VALUES(0x0);
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

And it will work as default constraint too:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (0x0), SomeOtherValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeOtherValue) VALUES('GUID by default');
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Hint:** This looks as if you have a user's table with GUIDs as IDs and this is the FK-id pointing to this table. In this case you will have to maintain a user with a zero-id as *dummy*. To be honest: I would rather recommend to have a nullable column and mark the *missing* value with a `NULL` instead with a *magic value*...